# Should planar Euclidean graphs be planar straight-line graphs?

Tags: graphs, euclidean-distance

An [Euclidean graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclideanGraph.html), by definition is

> A weighted graph in which the weights are equal to the Euclidean
>   lengths of the edges in a specified embedding

and a graph is called [planar](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlanarGraph.html) if

> it can be drawn in a plane without graph edges crossing

lastly, a [planar straight-line graph (PSLG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_straight-line_graph) is

> embedding of a planar graph in the plane such that its edges are mapped into straight line segments.

By these three definitions, I cannot conclude that if an Euclidean planar graph should be a PSLG or not.
For instance, given an Euclidean non-planar graph:

[image]

I can convert this graph into an Euclidean planar graph

[image]

by sticking with the definitions. Given the definitions above, the former one is a non planar straght-line graph whereas the latter one is a planar graph. Assume that the length of each edge is preserved. Then is the latter one still an Euclidean graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Fáry's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A1ry%27s_theorem) states that every planar graph can be drawn in such a way that its edges are (non-crossing) straight lines. Hence every planar graph is a planar straight-line graph.

However, this doesn't really have any bearing on the definition of Euclidean graph. According to the definition you link too, the edges need not be straight. A Euclidean graph is a planar graph in which the edge weights are their lengths in some specific (planar) embedding. In particular, a non-weighted graph isn't Euclidean any more than a cucumber.

Finally, the first graph in your question is planar – it's just that your specific embedding isn't a planar embedding.